# Http Request android

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to post information from an EditText into a url and then display the information from the web server on the application. I've tried several different ways to do this but I keep getting different error message everyway I try.

I think it has something to do with were I am coding the url but I have no idea where else to put it, any ideas?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
  final EditText post = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);


  button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
  {

      public void onClick(View v)
      { 

        System.out.println(executeHttpGetRequest("http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q="+ post.getText().toString() + "&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=9e87fcbce7114648121009"));

     }
  });

}  

private static String executeHttpGetRequest(String desiredUrl) throws Exception
{
    URL url = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    try
    {
        url = new URL(desiredUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        connection.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
        connection.connect();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    reader.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What error message do you get with the above version of the code?

Comment: I get an error message of "Unhandled exception type Exception" on the line with the url, I think I've put it in the wrong place but can't figure out where else it should go.

Comment: Wait, that is a compiler warning, not an error thrown by the code?  You are throwing an exception from within `executeHttpGetRequest` that is not being handled by a try/catch block, and is not being thrown by the calling method.  Refactor your code to either 1) not throw exceptions from `executeHttpGetRequest` or 2) catch and handle exceptions thrown by `executeHttpGetRequest`

Comment: Well that's what I am trying to do but I don't know how to, I'm new to developing android and this is my first app, that's why I need help.

Comment: In that case, remove your `throw e;` call. Then add a `return "";` after the end of your finally block.  Also remove `throws Exception` from your method declaration.